# Font style on this site is boring and not capturing eyes

Tags: feature-request, design, theme

Why this site's font style is  not capturing the eyes or it is so blurred? Is that only me who detects or is it a common problem?

Can't it look like the stackoverflow.com's font? at least visible. When I try to read questions or whatever, it makes me contract my lenses. If I'm asked about the fonts I would say very poor (colors very light, background ...)

**Let us compare**

[image: dba snapshot]

[image: SO snapshot]

I got my problem, the titles style and after opening a question the related links are so dim

Comment: It's intended to be very light. So far only one or two people have complained about the coloration, but on both occasions those were cleaned up pretty quickly. Is there something in particular you want to see?

Comment: "blurred"? It is #444 instead of black, but it is not blurred (at least on my screen). Maybe something to do with the contrast on your monitor?

Comment: @JackDouglas No I guess my screen is fine compared to other sites. Somewhat when I increase brightness it is fine but rarely I encounter in such situation. May be it is a matter of color preference. But even if so why don't I become uncomfortable with the colors of the many sites I visit.

Comment: I guess if it is not just you you'll see some upvotes coming your way :-)

Comment: I'll post a link in [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) to see if anyone else there agrees...

Comment: Maybe you can post a screen shot that demonstrates what you mean. It might truly be a difference in your monitor settings, resolution, or it could even be that you have custom CSS that is overriding something on the site. I don't see any of the text as blurry and while I do agree that the font looks different than Stack Overflow I don't necessarily agree that it's worse.

Comment: Are you talking about the main site or meta?  I agree that on meta the colors are a bit weak. [To hell with low-contrast font color!](http://contrastrebellion.com/)

Comment: @NickChammas Meta's issue is extreme for me, but I'm talking about the main site

Comment: I posted snapshot of my screen

Comment: After following @Nick's link I'm persuaded that we should ask for the contrast to be upped on both main and meta, +1 and thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: Same complaint... I squint everytime I come over here.  I spend time on stack-overflow so maybe it's just the difference.  If there were no stack overflow I might not even notice, but in comparison everything here is much more subdued.